# How can I stop execution while debugging in Visual Studio (2010)?

Tags: visual-studio

Here's the scenario.  I'm stepping through a function and realize at some point that I have found the bug I'm looking for and don't want the code to continue running, because if it does, I'll need to go and recreate the data scenario I had prior to running.  Ideally, I could just stop debugging and the rest of the code would not execute.  However, when I stop the debugger, VS apparently lets the code sequence complete.  Is there any way around this?  My only workaround is, in a web app, to just go do something else until a timeout exception is thrown.

Thanks!

Comment: *"However, when I stop the debugger, VS apparently lets the code sequence complete."* Really? This has never happened for me. What language are you working in? Visual Studio supports a whole bunch of them, but there isn't much detail given by your tags. You're clicking the "Stop" button, right?

Comment: Yes, really - this has always happened to me (well before 2010) and yes, I'm clicking the Stop button.